# Trying to write on a structure with a function

Tags: c, function, structure

I am trying to enter values into a structure I created but it cant seem to work for anything but the "char name[50]" value. Its the only thing that actually enters and outputs when i run the program. I am attaching a photo that shows the output as well. I cant understand why the other values aren't getting any value in it.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>

/* run this program using the console pauser or add your own getch, system("pause") or input loop */

struct ypallhlos{
   char name[50];
   int am;
   short type;
   int ohour;
   double misthos;
};

void gemismaPedion(char name2[50], int am2, short type2, int hour2, double misthos2);
void emfanishPedion(struct ypallhlos ypo);


int main() {
    struct ypallhlos yp1;

    gemismaPedion(yp1.name, yp1.am ,yp1.type ,yp1.ohour ,yp1.misthos);
    printf("\n");
    emfanishPedion(yp1);
   
   // PAFSI PROGRAMMATOS
    system("Pause");
}

void gemismaPedion(char name2[50], int am2, short type2, int hour2, double misthos2){
    struct ypallhlos ypo;
    printf("Dwse onoma : ");
    scanf("%[^\n]%*c", name2);
    printf("Dwse arithmo mitroou : ");
    scanf("%d", &am2);
    do{
        printf("Dwse typo ptixiou (1 ews 7): ");
        scanf("%hd", &type2);
    }
    while(type2 < 1 || type2 > 7);
    printf("Dwse yperwries : ");
    scanf("%d", &hour2);
    printf("Dwse mistho ypallhlou : ");
    scanf("%lf", &misthos2);
}

void emfanishPedion(struct ypallhlos ypo){
    printf("Onoma ypallhlou = %s \n", ypo.name);
    printf("Arithmos mitroou ypallhlou = %d \n", ypo.am);
    printf("Typos ptixiou ypallhlou = %hd \n", ypo.type);
    printf("Iperwries ypallhlou = %d \n", ypo.ohour);
    printf("Misthos ypallhlou = %lf \n", ypo.misthos);
}
```

***Input:***

> Dwse onoma : stackoverflow
>
> Dwse arithmo mitroou : 45
>
> Dwse typo ptixiou (1 ews 7): 4
>
> Dwse yperwries : 5
>
> Dwse mistho ypallhlou : 954

***Output:***

> Onoma ypallhlou = stackoverflow
>
> Arithmos mitroou ypallhlou = 0
>
> Typos ptixiou ypallhlou = 34
>
> Iperwries ypallhlou = 0
>
> Misthos ypallhlou = 0.000000
>
> Press any key to continue . . .

Comment: use printf like this: `printf("abcd %x", &var)` instead of `printf("abcd %x", var)`, check your uni textbook and compiler.

Answer (score 0):

C uses pass-by-value for function parameter passing.

If you want to change the parameter values from the called functions and have them reflected in the caller, you need to pass the address of those variables and in the called function, you need to

- collect them in appropriate pointer type variable
- write at the memory address received as the parameters.

That way, the values updated by the called function will reflect in the caller.

For example, you need to change the function definition to

```
void gemismaPedion(char name2[50], int *am2, short *type2, int *hour2, double *misthos2){
```

and call it like

```
gemismaPedion(yp1.name, &(yp1.am), &(yp1.type), &(yp1.ohour), &(yp1.misthos));
```

---

Approach without pointers:

You can get this done without using pointers, like

- Defined `gemismaPedion` as `struct ypallhlos gemismaPedion (void)`.
- Inside the function, define a variable struct ypallhlos temp;`
- Store the user inputs to specific variables, as you know.
- at last, use `return temp;`

then, from the `main()`, call it like

```
  struct ypallhlos yp1 = gemismaPedion ();
```

then, pass on `yp1` as you did, this should do the job.

Comment: Sadly we havent been teached pointers so far in the uni so im unable to understand how to write on memory address without using pointers.

Since i can write on the "name" , am i not supposed ot be able to write to the other values as well? What would be a solution in that case if i cant/am not teached the usage of pointers yet?

Comment: In that case, another way would be, to define a structure in the called function, fill it, and return it from the caller, and store the returned value in another variable of that structure type in the caller.

Comment: I tried the 1st solution but sadly it gave me only errors when it come to replacing as you showed me.

I tried to understand what you mean and what modifications to do in my code with your second solution but looks like im failing to fully understand what need to be done at your bullet points, or my compiler is kinda outdated and pops errors on me(Dev-c++).

I really appreciate your help, sorry for giving you a hard time though.

Comment: Can i do something similar with what i have done in the 2nd function?